# How to show/hide class per article/object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this pretty basic site (http://cimoril.dothome.co.kr/greece/aegean.html) that we are doing for responsive design practice at school and I want to add an onClick event per article.

How can I make it work per article and not per class? For example when I click one of the articles, I want only the specific article's class to be shown and not every article. If you click on the first image, all articles that have the .text class appear as well.

Just started learning JS/jQuery so I can't really explain well and haven't been able to find an answer while googling for a while.. I apologize in advance.

Code Snippet:

```js
$(".text").hide();

$("article").on("click", function() {
  $("p.text").show();
});


$("article").on("mouseleave", function() {
  $("p.text").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <article>
    <div class="bg bg1">
      <span>Aghios Efstratios</span>
      <p class="text text1">Aghios Efstratios is a small Greek island southwest of Lemnos and northwest of Lesbos.</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <div class="bg bg2">
      <span>Chios</span>
      <p class="text text2">Chios is the fifth largest of the Greek islands, situated in the Aegean Sea</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [edit] your question to show a sample of the relevant HTML. (Don't just rely on a link to an external site.)

Comment: Thank you and sorry, I thought it'd be easier to check the code there. I edited my initial post. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `this` reference within the click event to get the element the click event occurred on. Then you can get the paragraph within that article element.

On a side note, you don't need so many `$(document).ready()` handlers. You could group them all into one (unless you have a specific reason to do so).

e.g.

```js
$(".text").hide();

$("article").click(function() {
  $(this).find("p.text").show();
});

$("article").mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).find("p.text").hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <article>
    <div class="bg bg1">
      <span>Aghios Efstratios</span>
      <p class="text text1">Aghios Efstratios is a small Greek island southwest of Lemnos and northwest of Lesbos.</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <div class="bg bg2">
      <span>Chios</span>
      <p class="text text2">Chios is the fifth largest of the Greek islands, situated in the Aegean Sea</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It was easier than I thought...and no, I don't have a specific reason to have the ready handlers, I just don't know how to code [yet]. I appreciate the help in such a simple matter^^

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept the answer if it helped.